# js or jquery filtering of tagged content with pill selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, show-hide

Trying to figure out the correct way to filter content with jQuery (or vanilla JS).

I have the pills and the content in the basics of the html, css and js.

It technically works, but the jquery code is inelegant/repetitive and the fadein/out filtering effect is super janky rather than smooth.

I have a codepen that starts to get it right, but the fadeOut/In is a mess, especially if it is visible and then still visible when filtered, there's an odd delay and duplicate fadeout/in that occurs.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/SpacecaseArtist/pen/XWxbeev?editors=1111)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".pill").forEach((pill) => {
  pill.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".pill-selected").forEach((p) => {
      p.classList.remove("pill-selected");
    });
    pill.classList.add("pill-selected");
  });
});

$("#all").click(function() {
  $("#case-studies > *").fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("#case-studies > *").fadeIn(300);
  });
});

$("#ui").click(function() {
  $("#case-studies > *").fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("[data-tag~='ui']").fadeIn(300);
  });
});

$("#ux").click(function() {
  $("#case-studies > *").fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("[data-tag~='ux']").fadeIn(300);
  });
});

$("#product").click(function() {
  $("#case-studies > *").fadeOut(300, function() {
    $("[data-tag~='product']").fadeIn(300);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

ul li {
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

#divs {
  margin-left: 3.5em;
}

div span {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #272727;
  font: bold 2em Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  /* sits them next to each other */
}

.pill {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: system-ui;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #dddddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pill:not(.pill-selected):hover {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.pill-selected {
  background: #ff0055;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <button id="all" class="pill pill-selected" type="button">All</button>
  <button id="ui" class="pill" type="button">UI</button>
  <button id="ux" class="pill" type="button">UX</button>
  <button id="product" class="pill" type="button">Product</button>
</div>


<div id="case-studies">

  <div data-tag="ui ux product">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div data-tag="ui ux">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div data-tag="ui ux">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div data-tag="ux product">
    <span>4</span>
  </div>

  <div data-tag="ui product">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
  <div data-tag="product">
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
  <div data-tag="ui">
    <span>7</span>
  </div>
  <div data-tag="ux">
    <span>8</span>
  </div>

  <div data-tag="game">
    <span>9</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to get this to work, but I'm not sure how to appropriately target the individual cards with the data-tag to show while others hide.

```
 $(".filters button").click(function () {
  $(".case-studies").hide();
  $(".case-studies" + $(this).attr("data-tag")).show();
 });
```

But I'm very much a designer and not a FE expert. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below simplified code

```js
$('.filters').on('click', '.pill', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var id = $this.attr('id');
  $('.pill.pill-selected').removeClass('pill-selected');
  $this.addClass('pill-selected');
  $("#case-studies > [data-tag]").hide();
  if(id == 'all') {
    $("#case-studies > [data-tag]").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $("#case-studies > [data-tag~='" + id + "']").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: Genius, that's it!